# How do I convert a varchar value with a thousand separator to an int?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some dynamic sql that looks like this:

```
        INSERT INTO ' + @TempTable + '(' + @insertTempColumnList + ')
         SELECT ' + @insertTempColumnList + '
         FROM (
            SELECT ' + @insertTempColumnList + '
             FROM ' + @StagingDatabase + '.' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '
         ) AS src;'
```

One of the values produces this error message:

`Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '9,544' to data type int.`

9,544 is an int, so I don't know why TSQL doesn't recognize it as such. How do I convert '9,544' and values like it to an int?

Comment: You can use try_convert(money,'9,544')   ... it tends to be a little more forgiving.

Comment: As separators are ambiguous (this number would be "9 and a half and a bit" in some other locales) it's probably a good thing this conversion is not implicit. If *you* know all your values use commas for thousands separators, you can just `REPLACE` them away. Or, given that this is a dynamic query, a better approach would probably be to ensure your destination columns match your source column types to begin with. T-SQL is not a pleasant language to do such ETL transformations in in general, so another quite viable option is to write client code.

Comment: As a side note, that SQL looks like it could easily suffer injection; I *hope* it's not going to contain **any** using input (including details of objects made by a user).

Comment: Does the actual @Temptable destination have the correct data types for each column or are they all VARCHAR?  If they are, you need to explicitly convert all the non strings or you'll get errors like this or it will appear to work and things like dates might not implicitly convert properly.  

The actual convert is simple

select convert(int,replace('9,544',',',''))